# Defining functions between constants in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm a mathematician just starting to get used to Isabelle, and something that should be incredibly simple turned out to be frustrating. How do I define a function between two constants? Say, the function f: {1,2,3} \to {1,2,4}  mapping 1 to 1, 2 to 4 and 3 to 2?

I suppose I managed to define the sets as constants t1 and t2 without incident, but (I guess since they're not datatypes) I can't try something like

```
    definition f ::"t1 => t2" where 
"f 1 = 1" |
"f 2 = 4" | 
"f 3 = 2"
```

I believe there must be a fundamental misconception behind this difficulty, so I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of aspects to your question.

First, to get something working quickly, use the `fun` keyword instead of `definition`, like so:

```
fun test :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "test (Suc 0) = 1" |
  "test (Suc (Suc 0)) = 4" |
  "test (Suc (Suc (Suc 0))) = 2" |
  "test _ = undefined"
```

You cannot pattern match on any arguments directly in the head of the definition using the `definition` keyword, whereas you can with `fun`.  Note also that I have replaced the overloaded numeric literals (1, 2, 3, etc.) with the constructors for the `nat` datatype (`0` and `Suc`) in the pattern match.

An alternative would be to stick with `definition`, but push the case analysis of the function's argument inside the body of the definition using a `case` statement, like so:

```
definition test2 :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "test2 x ≡
     case x of
       (Suc 0) ⇒ 1
     | (Suc (Suc 0)) ⇒ 4
     | (Suc (Suc (Suc 0))) ⇒ 2
     | _ ⇒ undefined"
```

Note that definitions like `test2` are not unfolded by the simplifier by default, and you will need to manually add the theorem `test2_def` to the simplifier's simpset if you want to expand occurrences of `test2` in a proof.

You can also define new types (you cannot use sets as types, directly, as you are trying to do) corresponding to your two three-element sets with `typedef`, but personally I would stick with `nat`.

EDIT: to use `typedef`, do something like:

```
typedef t1 = "{x::nat. x = 1 ∨ x = 2 ∨ x = 3}"
  by auto

definition test :: "t1 ⇒ t1" where
  "test x ≡
     case (Rep_t1 x) of
     | Suc 0 ⇒ Abs_t1 1
     | Suc (Suc 0) ⇒ Abs_t1 4
     | Suc (Suc (Suc 0)) ⇒ Abs_t1 2"
```

Though, I don't really ever use `typedef` myself, and so this may not be the best way of using this and others may possibly suggest some other way.  What `typedef` does is carve out a new type from an existing one, by identifying a non-empty set of inhabitants for the new type.  The proof obligation, here closed by `auto`, is merely to demonstrate that the defining set for the new type is indeed non-empty, and in this case I am carving out a three-element set of naturals into a new type, called `t1`, so the proof is fairly trivial.  Two new constants are created, `Abs_t1` and `Rep_t1` which allow you to move back-and-forth between the naturals and the new type.  If you put a `print_theorems` after the `typedef` command you will see several new theorems about `t1` that Isabelle has automatically generated for you.

Comment: Thank you for that. In short, you can circumvent the problem by defining the functions as partial functions between the naturals instead, right? Could you tell me how you'd go about using typedef? My real concern is that after trying to develop a more complicated theory in Isabelle, I'd want to check how it deals with some particular cases in order to verify everything makes sense as expected (i.e say, using the theory Topology.thy define particular examples of topological spaces and continuous maps between them and test a few things).

Comment: @JoséSiqueira In answer to your first question: yes, you can just use a "partial" function on the naturals (in reality, HOL is a logic of total functions, and what looks like a partial function really isn't).  As to how to use `typedef`: in your case, it will probably look something like my edit above.